# IE compatibility mode

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-9

I have the following code in a .js page that should open a report in a blank page. This will only work if the site is added to the compatibility list of my IE11.

```
window.open("RosterList.aspx?strWhere= " + strWhere + "&strSort=" + strSort, '_blank');
```

My users are on IE9 and when they select the report it just displays a blank screen and a spinning loading icon.
If they go into their IE and add the site to their compatibility list, the report will display. 
The question is ... what to I need to write in my application that will force the site into compatibility mode. My MasterPage already contains the statement

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE9" />
```

but this has no effect?

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
```

Comment: I have tried that and there was no effect. It still only got the Loading... graphic, but thank you.